# Using Jquery with Twig

Tags: jquery, twig

I am trying to use J query with tiwg and have a few files that i need to include into the html template. I have a base.html template that then gets extended by other templates as shown below. Every time i add my reference to the required JQuery script the page doesn't load. I must be doing something wrong.

Thanks

```
 {% extends "base.html" %}

    {% block content %}
    <!-- page content -->

    {% endblock %}
    {% block javascripts %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ assets('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ assets('js/wizard/jquery.smartWizard.js') }}"></script>

    {% endblock %}
```

i have added the jquery to the top of the page rather than the bottom and i still cqannot get the jquery smart wizard to work , here is my code. The references to the jquery are in the base.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<!-- page content -->

<div class="row">
 <div id="wizard" class="swMain">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#step-1">
          <label class="stepNumber">1</label>
          <span class="stepDesc">
             Step 1<br />
             <small>Step 1 description</small>
          </span>
      </a></li>
    <li><a href="#step-2">
          <label class="stepNumber">2</label>
          <span class="stepDesc">
             Step 2<br />
             <small>Step 2 description</small>
          </span>
      </a></li>
    <li><a href="#step-3">
          <label class="stepNumber">3</label>
          <span class="stepDesc">
             Step 3<br />
             <small>Step 3 description</small>
          </span>                   
       </a></li>
    <li><a href="#step-4">
          <label class="stepNumber">4</label>
          <span class="stepDesc">
             Step 4<br />
             <small>Step 4 description</small>
          </span>                   
      </a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="step-1">   
      <h2 class="StepTitle">Step 1 Content</h2>
       <!-- step content -->
  </div>
  <div id="step-2">
      <h2 class="StepTitle">Step 2 Content</h2> 
       <!-- step content -->
  </div>                      
  <div id="step-3">
      <h2 class="StepTitle">Step 3 Title</h2>   
       <!-- step content -->
  </div>
  <div id="step-4">
      <h2 class="StepTitle">Step 4 Title</h2>   
       <!-- step content -->                         
  </div>
</div>                   

 </div>
{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/wizard/jquery.smartWizard.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      // Initialize Smart Wizard
        $('#wizard').smartWizard();
  }); 
</script>


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Have you tried to add jQuery script one per one in order to identify if it's within a script ? Are you using Symfony ?

Comment: i have tried that and the page only loads when all of the scripts have been removed. I have only just started using Twig so i am sure im referencing something wrong.

Comment: Ok, do you get an error in browser console panel (F12) ? If it's something like this "jQuery/$ is not a function" then, follow Carlos answer

Comment: ... First test if is a twig problem or jQuery problem, try including the script tags and the javascript code inside the content block (ignore javascript block) and see what happens in the console

Answer (score 0):

This is a know problem when using symfony and twig render templates :

1. Note that your content is rendered before you javascript blocks !

Your base.html the file should look like :

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
   <head>
     <!-- Here your css files and jQuery-->
     <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ assets('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
     {% block content %}
     {# 
        The content of other files will be rendered here !
        That means you need to include jQuery before this point
        in your base.html
      #}

     {% endblock %}
    </body>
{% block javascripts %}
    {#if you include jquery here, the scripts that need jquery will fail because jquery exists since this point !#}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ assets('js/wizard/jquery.smartWizard.js') }}"></script>

{% endblock %}
</html>
```

Then in any extend file you'll be able to execute jQuery.

Note : If you have an existing javascript block in your base.html.twig file, then you **can't** create another one in a extended views because the content will be replaced (use {{parent()}} to solve this, read [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/parent.html))

Comment: Concerning the "note" part, you could use `{{ parent() }}` in extended views to keep JS scripts in parent template before adding new ones.

Comment: i have tried adding the jquery to the top of the html template but i still cant get any of my scripts to work.

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE

I think the main error is that you have a "**s**" in the asset call.

It should be asset without "**s**"

```
{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}
```

instead of

```
{{ assets('js/jquery.min.js') }}
```

---

Assuming jquery is called in base.html.twig, you can use {{ parent() }} to get the initial contents of the block javascripts when you override it in your template

So, your base.html is like this

```
{% block javascripts %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

And the template extending base.html

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/wizard/jquery.smartWizard.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Initialize Smart Wizard
            $('#wizard').smartWizard();
        }); 
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```